# How to make vscode problem matcher match the IAR ARM compiler error?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to match errors of this format generated by an IAR ARM compiler for the VSCode ProblemMatcher...

```
"d:\test\helloWorld.c",646  Warning[Pe223]:
function "printf" declared implicitly
```

With regex101.com I am able to match the first line message with this regex...

```
^"(.*)",(\d+)\s+((Warning|Error)\[Pe\d+\]):$
```

Alas, when put into my tasks.json file with the correct escape slashes. The vscode prompts that error in task.json.  [error in task.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39TkK.png)

```
"problemMatcher": {
   "owner": "cpp",
   "fileLocation": "absolute",
   "pattern": [
      // The regular expression for IAR ARM compiler. Example to match: 
      //   "d:\test\helloWorld.c",646  Warning[Pe223]:
      //   function "printf" declared implicitly
      {
         "regexp": "^"(.*)",(\\d+)\\s+((Warning|Error)\\[Pe\\d+\\]):$",
         // The first match group matches the file name which is relative.
         "file"    : 1,
         // The second match group matches the line on which the problem occurred.
         "location": 2,
         // The third match group matches the message
         "message" : 3,
         // The fourth match group matches the problem's severity. Can
         // be ignored. Then all problems are captured as errors.
         "severity": 4
      },
      {
         // The next line matches the message.
         "regexp": "^([^\\s].*)$",
         "message": 1               
      }
   ]
}
```

Then, I removed the "", and it became,

```
^(.*),(\\d+)\\s+((Warning|Error)\\[Pe\\d+\\]):$
```

At last, I receive output in the Problems tab after running the task that will generate these errors in the terminal of VSCode. The warning message and line number are correct. But the file does not match, and can't jump to file.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the answer from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio

`\"`      Match a double quotes

So the correct regexp is,

```
"regexp": "^\"(.+?)\",(\\d+)\\s+((Warning|Error)\\[Pe\\d+\\]):$",
```